# Can I use $V-E+F=k$ when dealing with spheres and great circles?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, 3d, spherical-geometry

> A **great circle** is a circle drawn on a sphere that is an "equator," i.e., its center is also the center of the sphere. There are $n$ great circles on a sphere, no three of which meet at any point. They divide the sphere into how many regions?
>
> (The Art and Craft of Problem Solving, Page $37$, Problem $2.2.14$)

$2.2.12$ asks about the relation between vertices, edges and faces on a $3\text{-d}$ polyhedron, which is simply $V-E+F=2$.

$2.2.13$ asks about the number of regions an infinite plane can be split into using $n$ non-parallel lines, no three of which meet at any point. Here I checked a few cases, determined that $k=1$ and used $V-E+F=1$ to find that $f(n)=\frac 12 (n^2+n+2)$ where $f(n)$ is the number of regions.

For $2.2.14$, I am once again attempting to find $k$ such that I can use $V-E+F=k$. However, I am unsure how to define vertices or edges here. The few things I attempted all suggested different values of $k$ for different values of $n$.

I am unsure as to how I can determine $k$, as well as defining how vertices and edges are counted. 
Additionally, it would be really helpful if there was a simple way to manually count the number of edges, vertices and faces, especially since making $4$ great circle on a sphere and reading the number of faces, vertices and edges using Geogebra $3\text{-d}$ was very difficult.

Comment: Attend to 2.2.13.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Do I follow the same procedure?

Comment: It appears this has already been answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952532/recurrence-formula-for-division-of-a-sphere-by-n-great-circles?rq=1 .

Comment: It appears this has already been answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952532/recurrence-formula-for-division-of-a-sphere-by-n-great-circles?rq=1 .